# AngularJS - Focus on object in nested scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, focus

So I'm trying to have a nested scroll focus based on a key input. For this I've used `ng-focus` but I seem to have misunderstood it's purpose.

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michaeltotkorsgaard/29rneq5e/16/) shows what I've done so far. Whenever a match is found I set `ng-focus="x._focus"` to true, and in the console log it shows that this is happening. But the scroll is not moved to have the `input` field in focus. How is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey i did not really understand what you want , but check this and let me know if this is what you want [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjtz8xhr/)

```
function MyCtrl($scope) 
{
    $scope.list = []

    for(var i = 0; i < 500; i++){
        $scope.list.push({
        number: i,
        _focus: false
      })
    }

    $(document).keypress(function(e) 
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.list.length; i++)
        {
            if($scope.list[i].number === e.keyCode)
            {
                $scope.list[i]._focus = true
                console.info('found : ', $scope.list[i])
                $scope.$apply(); // Apply changes and change the false to true in dom

                $('#nestedScroll').animate(
                {
                    scrollTop: $("#nestedScroll span[scrollTo='true']").offset().top
                }, "slow");

                return
            } else {
                $scope.list[i]._focus = false
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Somewhat. I've updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wjtz8xhr/13/ so that it can find the item which we are looking for. One weird thing is that when you do it the first time around it works, if you then type in a number less than the first one it doesn't show it properly

Comment: sorry i did not understand you , but what i gave you as an exemple works perfectly and you can find the item you ware looking for